# Excel VBA validate any value

Tags: excel, vba

I am wondering is there a way to `xlValidateAnyValue`? I have made a userform for inputting comment in a Validation box. So basically I don't need any certain validation but just comment. I know how to create a comment but I would like to do it validation way.

```
Private Sub CommandButton25_Click()
With ActiveCell.Validation
 .Add Type:=xlValidateWholeNumber
 .InputTitle = Me.TextBox1.Value
 .InputMessage = Me.TextBox2.Value

End With

Unload InputForm

End Sub
```

Comment: You could use the formula `=TRUE` as your validation condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the documentation of the [Validation object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.validation) you will find that the [Validation.Type property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.validation.type) has a [XlDVType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldvtype) which allows the following:

```
Type:=xlValidateInputOnly
```